# How mock Postgres in WebFlux

Tags: java, postgresql, junit, mockito

Good morning:

I have problems to mock a test that uses Postgres, when put

Tengo problemas al mockear un test que utiliza el postgres, If I put dummy data to the postgres connection string I get an error when compiling. Attached structure and build.

```
spring:
 datasource:
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example?currentSchema=public
      username: usuario
      password: password
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
2023-05-29 09:47:37.357 ERROR 8880 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication                   : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/ingrid/ms/aplicacion/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/ingrid/ms/aplicacion/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "usuario"
```

The language used is Java and tests JUnit and Mockito.

Do you know how else I can mock?